# Why is the electrode potential of copper positive when hydrogen is more electronegative than copper?

Tags: electrochemistry, electronegativity, reduction-potential

Both copper and zinc has an electronegativity that is smaller than hydrogen, but why does copper have a positive electrode potential while zinc has a negative one? And lead (which has a greater electronegativity than hydrogen) does also have a negative electrode potential.

Comment: In short, because electrode potentials have (almost) nothing to do with electronegativity.